# Multiple indices in read_excel in DataFrame (TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I did some research and still couldn't get my code working correctly.

I am trying to read an excel file into a dataframe. 
[Excel file - Book1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6t73.jpg)

```html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

file1 = "Book1.xlsx"
Infile = pd.read_excel(file1,Sheet_Name = 'Sheet6',index_col =['DOCO','LEAST','LEASPN'])
Infile.head()
print "Test"
```

How can  I specify that the table has three columns in the index and import into a data frame?

This is the error I am getting.

```html
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 238, in read_excel
    false_values=false_values, squeeze=squeeze, **kwds)
  File "C:\py\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 518, in _parse_excel
    last = data[offset][col]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the indices of these columns rather than their names. This is the reason you are getting the

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

because `index_col` expects integer indices as is also clear from the name **`index`_col**

Assuming your `['DOCO','LEAST','LEASPN']` columns have indices 2, 6, 8 respectively, you can pass them to `index_col`. For example

```
file1 = "Book1.xlsx"
Infile = pd.read_excel(file1,Sheet_Name = 'Sheet6', index_col =[2, 6, 8])
```

From the [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) (emphasis mine)

> index_col : **int, list of int**, default None
>   Column (0-indexed) to use as the row labels of the DataFrame. Pass None if there is no such column .....

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am newbie with Python and when I saw there was a "bug" related to this in other posts, I wanted to make sure I was doing the right thing before looking at an alternate solution. Appreciate your help.